# Can we use third party payment gateway in ios In-App Purchase?

Tags: ios

One of our clients have approached us to develop an app like Yelp where Restaurants with Happy Hours can list their business, which is showed to end consumer of the app when they are trying to find nearest Restaurants.

Business Owner have to purchase subscription in order to do that, we wanted to clarify whether we can use third party payment processor like Pay Pal as the same service is also going to be available in Android platform as well.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the 
[tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour),
 have a look around, and read through the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) ,
 in particular [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) 
 and [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 1):

In essence, this is **not possible**. Third party payment walls are against the strict rules of the payment control and income sharing of App Store guidelines.

Take a look at Apple's [App Store Review Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/) for more information.